# How to pass object attributes to report (RDLC) C#

Tags: c#, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I want to fill a report page with attributes of an object and display it in a reportViewer.
This object I selected before in the Report Wizard and a DataSet was generated.

[image: Report Designer]

Now I am trying to use this code to add the values to the report.
I am putting that single object into a list because "ReportDataSource" doesn't accept objects.
But when I run it, the report is blank and the values were not displayed.
What am I doing wrong? I am new to reports and I hope someone can help me.

```cs
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyObject myobject = new MyObject();
        myobject.Artikelnr = "12345";
        myobject.Aussehen = 1;
        myobject.Bemerkungen = "cool";

        List<MyObject> objectlist = new List<MyObject>();
        objectlist.Add(myobject);

        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", objectlist); 
            
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        reportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by object attributes? Do you mean the fields not being displayed on the report? Shouldn't the textbox value be like [Artikelnr]? What's inside <<Ausdr>>?

Comment: Yes, the fields on the report should contain the object attributes, but they are empty.

Comment: Thats the Value for "<Ausdruck>": "=First(Fields!Artikelnr.Value, "DataSet1")"
Name of this field ist "ArtikelNr.:".

Comment: I think ist meens that it is the first column of the datatable? Is that right?

Comment: Good to know. Frankly I don't see any problem in this section of the code or the formula. I think you can also check the way your rdlc is opened / referenced, the tags and structure of the reportviewer in aspx and etc. Upvoted for more attention.

Comment: Code looks good, and I verified on my side that it should work. Try to reduce complexity as much as possible, maybe even create a new project or report where you do only the minimum necessary steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you either refresh the report with the green refresh arrow on the toolbar and/or delete all the .data files. Visual Studio caches data results and only refreshed when a parameter changes, the dataset is refreshed. You could be running into a cache issue.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/create-rdlc-report-using-dataset-in-Asp-Net/) is helpful, you can download this project and will test it. Before adding a data source, is better to clear it.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyObject myobject = new MyObject();
        myobject.Artikelnr = "12345";
        myobject.Aussehen = 1;
        myobject.Bemerkungen = "cool";

        List<MyObject> objectlist = new List<MyObject>();
        objectlist.Add(myobject);

        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", objectlist); 

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();  

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        reportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```